# Why I got 0 when storing d value in my PHP code

Tags: php

I am trying to update my database record of sum of two rows 
but I got just zero even thought it reads from records. 
This is my code 
d is `show = 0` ?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mcse123#";
$dbname = "data";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$a = isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : '';
$b = isset($_GET['b']) ? $_GET['b'] : '';
$c = isset($_GET['c']) ? $_GET['c'] : '';
$d = isset($_GET['d']) ? $_GET['d'] : '';
$d=$b+$c;
$sql = "UPDATE d1 SET  d='$d' WHERE a=1";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully" ;
    echo "$d";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Is `echo "$d"` the one that shows that 0?

Comment: do `var_dump($d);` before `$sql` and let us know the result

Comment: `I am trying to update my database record of sum of two rows` looks like you're trying to update your database for the record of two GETS. Are you sure you're getting values in `$_GET['b']` and `$_GET['c']`?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting values in $_GET['b'] and $_GET['c']? – IsThisJavascript     i didnt get the values of b,c also @IsThisJavascript

Comment: @mohamedeltoum Then you're not passing them in your url... `$_GET` are sent in the url like: `www.example.com/page.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4`